# maven-surefire-report-plugin generates report not in right format

Tags: maven, report, parent-child, maven-surefire-plugin

I started to use maven-surefire-report-plugin for generating test reports.
My project is composed of parent and two children.

```
--helloworld--pom.xml
  --app1--pom.xml
  --app2--pom.xml
```

app1 generates sources for app2 and app2 contains sources for creating war including tests.

Parent pom.xml file looks

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.2</version>
            </plugin> 
         </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

When I run

> mvn verify

it builds the project and run tests in the integration phase which is correct. If I browse the `app2/target/site` it contains report,but a little corrupted. The problem is that css and images folders are missing and that is why the report looks incomplete.[image: Report]

Second problem is when I run

> mvn site

it generates html project reports for every folder (helloworld,app1,app2), but they are not linked correctly. I mean when I open index.html in parent folder and want to click on link app1 it gets lost,because it points wrongly. Is there any solution how to overcome these two problems?
Well I am not insisting on maven surefire report plugin for generating reports for test. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using such ancient version ? See http://maven.apache.org/surefire/

Comment: Ok changed it to version 2.19 and it does not generate anything :(.

Comment: Always keep maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin and maven-surefire-report-plugin in sync...

Comment: Problem is that now neither the earlier version works. I do not know what I changed :(

Comment: If I do mvn verify, it just creates surefire-reports and there is xml and txt file which is not what I wanted to use. I would like to have nice html report.

Comment: Can put that project somewhere like on Github so i could take a look?

Comment: Well I have never tried it and I do not know how to put it to GitHub. I would like to do it, but I found that I have to do mvn surefire-report:report to generate it. Can it be done automatically during the verify phase?

Comment: Ah...so you have only defined the plugin in pluginManagement but not in reporting...See here https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/usage.html

Comment: No, I had some configuration when I invoked mvn verify and report was automatically generated. How to include it after integration-testing phase?

Comment: Why this does not work?
 <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.19</version>
     <executions>
      <execution>
       <phase>verify</phase>
       <goals>
        <goal>report</goal>
       </goals>
      </execution>
     </executions>
    </plugin>

Comment: I got it. It works only if the plugin is defined in child pom.xml file. Why? Is it a bug?